# SQL Check Datetime Existence within multiple columns

Tags: sql

I've a BillDate as date, and a Mark as bit column in First table.
(Mark=0 by default)

In Second table I've FromDate as date, and ToDate as date Column.

I want to set Mark=1 if BillDate is exists between FromDate & ToDate

Let Say In First Table the data is

```
----------------------------
BillDate             | Mark
----------------------------
2012-11-10 11:15:30  | 0

2012-12-12 09:00:00  | 0
```

In Second Table the data is

```
---------------------------------------------
FromDate             | ToDate
---------------------------------------------
2012-11-01 07:00:00  | 2012-11-09 23:59:59

2012-12-08 07:00:00  | 2012-12-15 23:59:59
```

So in the above scenario only the second row from First table
which is having, `BillDate->2012-12-12 09:00:00` will be `Mark as 1`
because it comes between second row of second table

I hope I've explained my scenario,

Comment: Side note - it's almost always better to use semi-open intervals when working with `datetime`s - an inclusive `FromDate` and exclusive `ToDate`, in this instance. Unless your intention (in this case) was to specifically exclude anything that occurred at, say, `2012-11-09T23:59:59.317`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what flavor of SQL you are using and if there are any other fields which link your tables. Therefore assuming a cross join how about this:

```
Update ft
SET mark = 1
FROM FirstTable ft, SecondTable st
WHERE BillDate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work in most/all DMBS (as none specified)

```
UPDATE  FirstTable
SET     Mark = 1
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    SecondTable
            WHERE   FirstTable.BillDate BETWEEN SecondTable.Fromdate AND SecondTable.ToDate
        );
```